# Import Cognito Forms data from another page

Tags: cognito-forms

I'm creating a form for booking airport transfers to several cities in a tourist zone. On the home page of the website I create just a search "engine" for the prices. The client searches for the price to the transfer and if they are interested in booking the transfer, after they click *"Book Now"*, the client will be redirected to another page where he can complete the rest of the data (name, email, etc.). I want this because, without this feature, the client will have to re-enter the data.

What I want to export is field from: and field to:. That is the origin and destination of the transfer. Then, there is another field with number of people, that only have two fields. And for last, just a yes/no question, that is if client wants to book return or not. With all of this, I have the price of the transfer. What I want is to export this data to another page, so the client only has to book date and personal info, and doesn´t need to insert data in the fields from. and to:, nº of people, and return yes/no again in the second form.

Is there a way to import the data that the client already inserted in the first form to the second form and continue to complete the fields?

Comment: I'm a developer with Cognito Forms. This sounds like a very specific use case, and I have a few other questions about what would need to be sent over and how you would be collecting it. Can you submit a Support Request(https://www.cognitoforms.com/supportrequest/)?

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways you can accomplish this task.

1. You can use the "Page Break" Field feature to separate the pages so the user only sees the information you want them to see, then they click next to enter another set of information.
2. You can use "Redirect URL" to transfer the data from one page to another. The tutorial is here https://www.cognitoforms.com/support/65/data-integration/prefilling-a-form